# Setting the delegate of a custom UITextView Delegate in Xcode

Tags: xcode, delegates, uitextview, init

I have a class that creates a custom UITextView and initializes it with hint text. The problem that I am having is that when I try to set the delegate of the UITextView inside of the initializer, the delegate functions are not called. I am also not completely sure if the textView class should be the delegate.
Below is the custom UITextView class:

```swift
class TextView: UITextView, UITextViewDelegate {
    var test: TextView?
    var hintLabel, smallHintLabel: UILabel!
    var underline: UIView!

    // MARK: - Init
    
    /// Initialize text field
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - text: Text field text
    ///   - hintText: Text field hint text (a.k.a. placeholder/description)
    ///   - isLight: Whether text field is light style
    convenience init(text: String? = nil, hintText: String, isLight: Bool = false) {
        self.init(frame: .zero, textContainer: .none)
        
        self.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 57).isActive = true
        //setting the delegate
        test = TextView()
        self.delegate = test
        
        // hint
        hintLabel = UILabel()
        hintLabel.text = hintText
        hintLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: largeSize, weight: weight)
        hintLabel.textColor = hintColor
        hintLabel.alpha = text == nil || text!.isBlank ? 1 : 0
        self.addSubview(hintLabel)
        
        hintLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        hintLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor, constant: insets.top / 2).isActive = true
        hintLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        hintLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        
        // small hint
        smallHintLabel = UILabel()
        self.smallHintLabel.text = hintText
        self.smallHintLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: smallSize, weight: weight)
        self.smallHintLabel.textColor = hintColor
        self.smallHintLabel.alpha = text == nil || text!.isBlank ? 0 : 1
        self.addSubview(smallHintLabel)
        
        smallHintLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        smallHintLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
        smallHintLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        smallHintLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        
        // text
        self.text = text
        self.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: largeSize, weight: weight)
        self.textColor = textColor
        self.tintColor = isLight ? .white : Color.blue
        self.keyboardAppearance = isLight ? .dark : .light
        
        // underline
        underline = UIView()
        underline.backgroundColor = lineColor
        self.addSubview(underline)
        
        underline.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        underline.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        underline.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        underline.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        underline.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1).isActive = true
        
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect, textContainer: NSTextContainer?) {
        super.init(frame: frame, textContainer: textContainer)
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

/// Adjusts the position of the hint text when text is changed in field
    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        print(textView.text)
        if self.text?.isEmpty ?? true {
            moveHintUp()
        } else {
            moveHintUp()
        }
    }
```

I am creating an instance of this function and adding it to a view.

```
class MessageComposeView: UIView, UITextViewDelegate {
    
    var textField: TextView!
    private var sendButton: SendButton!
    
    weak var delegate: MessageComposeViewDelegate?

    init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        
        // background
        
        // text field
        textField = TextView(hintText: "Type a message")
        textField.delegate = self
        self.addSubview(textField)
        
        textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true
        textField.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: -30).isActive = true
        textField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 16).isActive = true
        textField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
        textField.sizeToFit()
        
        // send button
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
    
    
    // MARK: - Actions
    
    /// Called when the message text changes
    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        sendButton.setState(textField.text?.isBlank == true ? .disabled : .normal)
        
        let size = CGSize(width: 200, height: 999999)
        let estimatedSize = textField.sizeThatFits(size)

        textField.constraints.forEach { constraint in
            if constraint.firstAttribute == .height {
                constraint.constant = estimatedSize.height
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you aren't actually calling the initializer that you mean to be.

For example, if you call `TextView()`, your `convenience init` *will not* be called. It will, however, if you call `TextView(hintText: "")` or any other variations of the initializer that you've created.

Secondly, although it's not directly related to the above issue, I question why you're creating *another* `TextView` and assigning it to be the delegate. Why not just assign the delegate to `self`?

Comment: I am calling the convenience init in another file when I create an instance of this class. As to why I am creating a variable for the TextView(), it is because if I just assign it to TextView() it gives me an a warning that the memory will be deallocated immeaditely as it is a weak reference.

Comment: Please show your code for where you're calling it -- I've tested it and it works fine when I call the initializer explicitly using the format I gave you. As to the second part, I'm not suggesting you assign `TextView()` to the delegate, I'm suggesting you assign `self`, eg `self.delegate = self`.

Comment: For you the  func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) executes when you set self.delegate = self inside of the convenience init? I have also updated the original question to show where this is called

Comment: Yes, I added only the `TextView` and set `delegate = self` within the `init`. You've complicated things a little by *also* setting the delegate within `MessageComposeView`. Only *one* delegate can get called, so the one in `MessageComposeView` should get called. Is that taking place for you?

Comment: Yes, the one in the MessageComposeView is called. What are my options? write all of the code in the func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) of the MessageComposeView? or is there a way to make both execute?

Comment: Your suggestion would work. Or, you could declare an additional delegate property (it'd have to have another name, like `outerDelegate`) and call that from within the `textViewDidChange` implementation inside `TextView`... Lots more options, too -- just an architectural decision. Let me know if you need one of those written up.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @jnpdx, you have saved me a lot of hours trying to figure this out. You have been extremely helpful! Thank you

Comment: Great. You can upvote the answer using the arrow if it was helpful and mark it as correct with the checkmark if you deem it acceptable.